# What is SQL Warning Code: 3604, SQLState: S0000

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, jdbc

I've a multi-threaded Java application which uses SQL Server over JDBC over Hibernate 4.3.1 over Spring 4.1.7.

I see a lot of following warnings in my log file:

```
WARN  SqlExceptionHelper:232 - SQL Warning Code: 3604, SQLState: S0000
WARN  SqlExceptionHelper:233 - Duplicate key was ignored.
```

What does they mean?

I've looked for [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714687.aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712451.aspx) resources but couldn't find my numbers.

Comment: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1499275-392-1.aspx

Comment: Are you sure that Warning code 3604 and SQLState S0000 just means "Duplicate key was ignored" ?

Comment: No, I am not sure of anything.  But looks relevant.